# How to Delete Redundant Indexes from Filtered Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a filtered MultiIndexed pandas dataframe, `df`, and I want to get rid of the indexes which have been filtered out. How can I do this?

The code I used to filter is `df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x : len(x) == 2)`.

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x : len(x) == 2)
df1.index = df1.index.remove_unused_levels()
```